# How to properly install react-native-navigation on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

After switching to *react-native-navigation* from *react-navigation* my app cant launch properly.

It either appears as a blank screen or immedialy switches to the background without ability to switch back. Shaking the device or remote command `adb shell input keyevent 82` does not show the developer menu.

Fresh app created with `react-native init` results in the same.

In both cases I went strictly through these steps: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android

Launching example app does not work properly either but it starts and I can use dev menu although the redux example works fine for me.

I have found a lot of people had the same problem before but without a solution. https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2737#issuecomment-367812629, it said that the navigation works and the problem is in JS side. How to modify the JS app to work with this navigation system though?

Comment: Are you properly initializing the Navigator on app startup with ```Navigation.startSingleScreenApp()```

Comment: thanks for mentioning single screen app. That actually works with `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    screen: 'Screen1',
    title: 'Screen1',
  }
});` where Screen1 is simple React component and it is registered with title Screen1 before.

But startTabBasedApp is making the app just switch to background.

Comment: @RadoslavKarlík did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of people facing a blank screen issue after `react-native-navigation` installation. I came across two problems that can lead to a blank screen when you start implementing `RNN`.

1. This is the mistake even I did. Once you change your `MainActivity` and `MainApplication` as per the doc then you have to change the way you start your main component as per the `RNN` in `Javascript` side
2. Another issue is starting a tab based app but the icons provided by you don't exist.

I also came across another problem when using `RNN` in which `React Native` searches for `index.android.js` instead of `index.js`.
Just override `createReactNativeHost` method and implement `getJSMainModuleName`

Add this to `MainApplication`

```
@Override
protected ReactNativeHost createReactNativeHost() {
    return new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
    };
}
```

Another issue lies in this line

`missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative55"`

Document says `use reactNative55: Support for React Native 0.55 and above`
but if you are using `RN56` then you have to change this to

`missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative56"`

Comment: can you provide github repo that can easily understandable.